# Why did filmmakers choose the particular dog breeds that are showcased?

Tags: analysis, production, best-in-show

The 2000 "mockumentary" film, [*Best in Show*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0218839/) direced by Christopher Guest and co-written by Eugene Levy follows five separate dogs and their owners to the Mayflower Kennel Club Dog Show.

The dog breeds that are showcased are as follows:

- "Winky" - [**Norwich Terrier**](http://www.akc.org/dog-breeds/norwich-terrier/)

  [image]
- "Beatrice" - [**Weimaraner**](http://www.akc.org/dog-breeds/weimaraner/)

[image]

- "Hubert" - [**Bloodhound**](http://www.akc.org/dog-breeds/bloodhound/)

[image]

- "Rhapsody in White" - [**Standard Poodle**](http://www.akc.org/dog-breeds/poodle/)

[image]

- "Miss Agnes" - [**Shih Tzu**](http://www.akc.org/dog-breeds/shih-tzu/)

[image]

While "Winky" wins the coveted Best in Show title, three out of the other four dogs impressed the judges enough to win "Best in Class" which qualifies them to compete in the final "Best in Show" with Winky.

**Is there a reason why filmmakers chose to use these particular dog breeds when making this film?**

Seeing how the film "mocks" actual dog shows,
**Is there any evidence that Christopher Guest and Eugene Levy chose to showcase these particular breeds based on actual "Best in Show" winners of [The Westminster Kennel Club](http://www.westminsterkennelclub.org/) dog show?**

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2351/49).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A little history may have contributed to one decision.  A Norwich Terrier won the 1994 Westminster Dog Show, and a [documentary film maker, Leandra Little](http://www.akc.org/news/woman-inspired-best-in-show-movie/), followed it all the way.

I believe, however, that the dogs' owners drove the bulk of the casting decisions. The breeds were picked to complement the characters. For instance, Rhapsody in White, was owned by a very wealthy couple. A Standard Poodle seems like the kind of dog they'd own -- elegant, a princess. Likewise, Harlan Pepper, a country man, owns a stereotypical country dog, a bloodhound. What kind of dog would a well-to-do gay couple own? A fancy Shih Tzu, naturally. Weimaraners are a bit high strung and energetic, and much like the Swans capable of inappropriate behavior. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weimaraner):

> Weimaraner requires appropriate training to learn how to be calm and
>   control its behavior.

The Flecks, the most down-to-earth competitors, have the most down-to-earth dog in the bunch.  If Winky wasn't in the show, it's not clear that anyone would pick out Winky as a show dog.

In short, they fit the director's vision of what kind of dogs the characters would own, and would help drive the story.

Answer (score -1):

Because these dog breeds are easy to train.

Like on this page you can see which breeds are easy to train and why. [click me](http://iheartdogs.com/12-easiest-dog-breeds-to-train/)

[or this link](http://www.dogbreedslist.info/easy-to-train-dog-breeds/#.V4Yv7DUqswI)

Comment: Hi - The 1st link that you provided only lists the poodle as highly trainable out of the dog breeds in the question.  The 2nd link ranks the poodle high, but the next dog breed on that list from the question is the weimaraner and it ranks #34.  Could you please provide more information on why the ***filmmakers*** chose these particular dog breeds to showcase?  If you believe that it is because they are easily trainable, please provide more information supporting this. Thanks :)

Comment: @steelershark sorry I am just a Pogrammer thats all i've got